# Git - Revert Large commit history from Pushed Head to wrong branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-reset, git-revert, git-rewrite-history

A colleague of mine somehow pushed his HEAD revision of a release branch my team is working on to our main development branch.  (This would be 145 commits improperly pushed)

I want to keep our commit history clean so I am toying with the idea if I should do anything, or just create a new Development branch to begin working on.

I cannot simply do a

```
git revert <last-trusted-sha>..HEAD
```

Because there are multiple merges on the branch (From when we do a pull request and Git creates a merge remote_currentbranch to currentbranch).

Is there any way to resolve this easily?  Or do I just go commit by commit until it is corrected?

Thanks

Comment: How did your colleague push HEAD version of `release` branch to `development` branch? Which command did he use?

Comment: `git rebase -i` and drop all unwanted commits?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I am unsure of how it happened, they were using eclipse EGit plugin.

Comment: @RemusRusanu that could work well.  Thanks!  Also, my teammate somehow managed to set our release branch to track both the development branch remote and release remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recover `development` branch, you can use below commands:

```
git checkout development
git reset --hard HEAD~145 
git push -f
```

Or if you know the last commit sha-1 value on the `development` branch before commits on the `release` branch were pushed to the `development` branch, you can also use `git reset --hard <last commit>` to replace the command `git reset --hard HEAD~145`. Then the `development` branch would be recovered.

Comment: Thanks this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

This should be quite easy to fix technically:

- Find the previous, correct commit that you wish to restore.
- `git branch develop THEHASH -f`
- `git push origin develop -f`

Normally you would not do something like this out of respect for your colleagues. But in this case, everything is broken anyways already, so you might as well.

To find the correct commit 145 steps back,  `git reflog` might be of help, unless you can spot it easily using `git log`.